# writing comma separated strings to single cell in csv without any packages

Tags: python, nlp

I'm new to python and trying to solve the following problem:
writing below list as single column to csv file

```py
mylist=['emilysmom718',
 'okiemama18',
 'Dave Melton',
 'Anonymous',
 'Anonymous',
 'The Mazatlan, Post',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'bripat9643',
 'Jeff Vorva',
 'Karen Caffarini',
 'USA TODAY',
 'Proud Boys organizer, rioter who attacked Capitol officer arrested',
 'Proud Boys organizer, rioter who attacked, Capitol officer arrested']

with open('test.csv','w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
  for s in mylist:
    f.write("%s\n" % s)
```

However, with above code values with a comma are pushed to the next cell of the following column.

P.S: I'm new to python sorry if the query is naive.

Comment: You want every item in your list in its own row, and every row should have 1 column? Or you want the whole list in a single column in a single row?

Comment: its whole list in a single column in a single row, I'm trying to do without any package (like csv or pandas) to master my python

Comment: Okay, how do you want the list in the cell? Like a python list `[1, 2, 3]` structure or something else?

Comment: so each element in the list would stick to one cell. for example: element '1' in the list would go to first cell,first row (A1) and second cell to (A2) and so on. Something like this: https://imgur.com/Emn6PjU

Comment: The csv format allows you to have quotes around each field. Since your data has no quotes in it, this would work: `f.write('"%s"\n' % s)`. Notice I changed your double quotes to single ones so I didn't have to escape the double quotes I added.

Comment: If you also wanted to support quotes in the input, you could escape them on the fly: `f.write('"%s"\n' % s.replace('"', '\\"'))`

Comment: One last suggestion, maybe the csv format lets you escape commas to ignore them? If so, this variant could help: `f.write("%s\n" % s.replace(",", "\\,"))`

Answer (score 0):

There are some commas in your elements of your list, example: 'The Mazatlan, Post'. When you open the csv file in your excel application, you need to tell it to treat commas as strings. I ran your code and it works fine, check out the excel settings here: [screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51kWF.png)

Comment: thanks for your reply. But the code gives inaccurate results even when I give delimiter as comma: https://imgur.com/CvXIQIA

Comment: Try this: ```f.write("%s\n" % s.replace(',',''))
``` This works, you don't have to to mess with the excel settings.

Comment: @Aswath you're deleting the commas here, so you're changing the values.